# Flutter webview inside the dialog

Tags: flutter

```
Widget webview() {
    return Container(
        child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      child: Row(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          new GestureDetector(
            child: Text(
              'About',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: const Color(0XFF5867DD)),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              openWebview();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
  Widget openWebview() {
    return Container(
      child: WebviewScaffold(
        url: "https:www.google.com/",
        withZoom: true,
        withLocalStorage: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am creating webview inside my flutter app the issue is i want to open the webview inside the dialog when the textview is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it in a MaterialPageRoute like

```
  Widget openWebview() {
        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
return Container(
      child: WebviewScaffold(
        url: "https:www.google.com/",
        withZoom: true,
        withLocalStorage: true,
      ),
    );

            },
            fullscreenDialog: false
        ));
  }
```

Comment: i tried this code the webview is opening normally.i want webview inside the dialog box

Answer (score 0):

```
String? url = "Here add your url";


showDialog(
            context: context,
             builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                                   content:  Container(                                       
                                 width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.6,
                            heigh:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.5,
                                      child: WebviewScaffold(
                                        url: url ?? "",
                                        withZoom: true,
                                        withLocalStorage: true,
                                        initialChild: Container(
                                          child: const Center(
                                            child: Text("Loading....",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),**strong text**
                                  )
                                );
```